# Regex which matches the longer string in an OR

Tags: python, regex

## Motivation

I'm parsing addresses and need to get the address and the country in separated matches, but the countries might have aliases, e.g.:

```
UK == United Kingdom, 
US == USA == United States,
Korea == South Korea,
```

and so on...

## Explanation

So, what I do is create a big regex with all possible country names (at least the ones more likely to appear) separated by the OR operator, like this:

```
germany|us|france|chile
```

But the problem is with multi-word country names and their shorter versions, like:

`Republic of Moldova` and `Moldova`

Using this as example, we have the string:

```
'Somewhere in Moldova, bla bla, 12313, Republic of Moldova'
```

What I want to get from this:

```
'Somewhere in Moldova, bla bla, more bla, 12313'
'Republic of Moldova'
```

But this is what I get:

```
'Somewhere in Moldova, bla bla, 12313, Republic of'
'Moldova'
```

## Regex

As there are several cases, here is what I'm using so far:

```
^(.*),? \(?(republic of moldova|moldova)\)?(.*[\d\-]+.*|,.*[:/].*)?$
```

As we might have fax, phone, zip codes or something else after the country name - which I don't care about - I use the last matching group to remove them:

```
(.*[\d\-]+.*|,.*[:/].*)?
```

Also, sometimes the country name comes enclosed in parenthesis, so I have `\(?` and `\)?` around the second match group, and all the countries go inside it:

```
(republic of moldova|moldova|...)
```

## Question

The thing is, when there is an entry which is a subset of a bigger one, the shorter is chosen over the longer, and the remainder stays in the base_address string.
Is there a way to tell the regex to choose over the biggest possible match when two values mach?

### Edit

1. I'm using Python with built in re module
2. As suggested by m.buettner, changing the first matching group from `(.*)` to `(.*?)` indeed fixes the current issue, but it also creates another. Consider other example:

   'Department of Chemistry, National University of Singapore, 4512436 Singapore'

Matches:

```
'Department of Chemistry, National University of'
'Singapore'
```

Here it matches too soon now.

Comment: It would help if you told us what language you're working in, since different languages have different regex rules.

Comment: What language / pcre library are you using ? Cannot reproduce as pcre tries to be greedy by default see http://regexr.com?34tkd Issue must come from something in your regex, or you run it as non greedy

Comment: That said, look up the differences between "greedy quantifiers" and "reluctant quantifiers" and you might find the answer to your problem.

Comment: I'm using Python with the built in re module.

Comment: @Lepidosteus that is because you didn't use his full regex. Greediness is what causes the problem in first place, because the `.*` pushes the remainder of the regex as far as possible. Also greediness does not apply to alternation. The reason you get `republic of moldova` in your case is that, the corresponding match starts earlier in the target string (and matches are tried from left to right). Compare that with [this example](http://regexr.com?34tkg)

Comment: Also, regexr does not use PCRE, but ActionScript 3's built-in engine which implements the ECMA standard.

Comment: Do you actually need to solve this with regex? It sounds like you have some ambiguities (e.g., the `Singapore, Singapore` example from your comments to m.buettner's answer) that you can easily describe how to resolve in imperative terms but have no idea how to describe in regex terms.

Comment: @abarnert this is the best approach I could come up with, and the Singapore example is not ambiguous in my point of view, since the first time it appears is in the institution name, and the second it's the country name itself.

Comment: @abarnert I think I had misunderstood your suggestion. As m.buettner points out in his second edit, now I got the idea. I'll try that in case his second suggestion does not work. Thanks.

Comment: @alfetopito: That's my point: It's not ambiguous in your point of view, and you can express that point of view in terms of imperative rules very simply, but you, and even m.buettner, are having a very hard time expressing it in terms of regex. So maybe regex isn't the best answer here. Maybe you want regex plus some simple imperative string hacking, or maybe you want a real parser instead of regex, or…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy).

The `.*` right at the beginning tries to match as much as possible. That is everything until the end of the string. But then the rest of your pattern fails. So the engine backtracks, and discards the last character matched with `.*` and tries the rest of the pattern again (which still fails). The engine will repeat this process (fail match, backtrack/discard one character, try again) until it can finally match with the rest of the pattern. The first time this occurs is when `.*` matches everything up to `Moldova` (so `.*` is still consuming `Republic of`). And then the alternation (which still cannot match `republic of moldova`) will gladly match `moldova` and return that as the result.

The simplest solution is to make the repetition ungreedy:

```
^(.*?)...
```

Note that the question mark right after a quantifier does not mean "optional", but makes it "ungreedy". This simply reverses the behaviour: the engine first tries to leave out the `.*` completely, and in the process of backtracking it includes one more character after every failed attempt to match the rest of the pattern.

**EDIT:**

There are usually better alternatives to ungreediness. As you stated in a comment, the ungreedy solution brings another problem that countries in earlier parts of the string might be matched. What you can do instead, is to use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that ensure that there are no word characters (letters, digits, underscore) before or after the country. That means, a country word is only matched, if it is surrounded by commas or either end of the string:

```
^(.*),?(?<!\w)[ ][(]?(c|o|u|n|t|r|i|e|s)[)]?(?![ ]*\w)(.*[\d\-]+.*|,.*[:/].*)?$
```

Since lookarounds are not actually part of the match, they do not interfere with the rest of your pattern - they simply check a condition at a specific position in the match. The two lookarounds I have added ensure that:

1. There is no word character before the mandatory space preceding the country.
2. There is no word character after the country that is separated by nothing but spaces.

Note that I've wrapped spaces in a character class, as well as the literal parentheses (instead of escaping them). Neither is necessary, but I prefer these readability-wise, so they are just a suggestion.

**EDIT 2:**

As abarnert mentioned in a comment, how about not using a regex-only solution?

You could split the string on `,`, then trim every result, and check these against your list of countries (possibly using regex). If any component of your address is the same as one of your countries, you can return that. If there are multiples ones than at least you can detect the ambiguity and deal with it properly.

Comment: Hmm, it indeed fixes this issue, @m.buettner
But it opens up another one. 
Now it matches too early the country name, in case is appears in the previous part. E.g: `Department of Chemistry, National University of Singapore, Singapore` matches `Department of Chemistry, National University of` and leaves off the last `Singapore`.

Comment: @alfetopito hm, you could make that pattern in the beginning more restrictive. But if you don't know in which position the country is, (because you have optional parts before and after it), it's going to be tough, because you can't even count commas then. What you could do, is require that the country is not surrounded by other words: `^(.*?),?(?<!\w)[ ][(]?(c|o|u|n|t|r|i|e|s)[)]?(?![ ]*\w)...` which uses [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Well, the second suggestion could work if I didn't have something like this `Gainesville, FL, USA; tel/fax 352 846 2410` or this `HsinChu, 30010, Taiwan, ROC`. I'll accept you answer anyway since it answers both of my questions, but I have more cases than I would like to handle... Thanks for you help, though :)

Answer (score 2):

Sort all alternatives in regex, just create regex programatically by sorted (from longest to shortest) array of names. Then make whole regex in atomic group (PCRE engine has it, don't know if RE engine has it too). Because of atomic group, regex engine never backtrack to try other alternative in atomic group and so u have all alternatives sorted, match will always be the longest one.

Tada.